# Query more than 1 Database on DB2 v10

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, db2

I am writing an audit script that first collects info on the Linux server, then connects to the DB2 v10 instance via db2 CLI to run queries. It works perfectly with one database on the server. I created another database and ran the script. Now my results are mixing responses from both databases.

I've tried connecting to the first database via DB2 CLI and running the script, but the results are still mixed. How can I get results per database, or otherwise clearly indicate which result is from what database, when needed? I won't have database names beforehand because I am an external auditor.

The snippet below is what I run after I have gotten local Linux/AIX server information and start to connect to the DB2:

```
echo "=============================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

for i in `db2 list db directory | grep 'Database name' | awk '{print $4}'`;

do

echo "=============================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "Checking Database State"      >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "==============================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

state=$(db2 get db cfg for $i | grep 'HADR database role' | awk '{print $5}');

echo "Current state is $state"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

if [ $state = "STANDBY"  ]

then

echo "THIS DATABASE IS THE STANDBY, THIS OPERATION SHOULD BE PERFORMED ON THE PRIMARY"  >> $working_dir/$logfile

else
echo "========================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "CONNECTING TO DATABASE "    >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "========================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2  connect to $i  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "===================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "5. NODE DIRECTORIES"                   >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "===================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 list node directory show detail  >>$working_dir/$logfile ;


echo "=============================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "6. DATABASES ON THIS SERVER"     >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "=============================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 list db directory  >>$working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "===================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "7. AUDIT PARAMETERS IN THE DATABASE"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "===================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2audit describe  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "================================================"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "8. CURRENT LEVEL OF INSTALLED DATABASE SOFTWARE"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "================================================"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2level  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "================================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "9. APPLICATIONS CURRENTLY ACCESSING THE DATABASE"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "================================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 list applications  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "===================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo  "10. DATABASE DBA-LEVEL ASSIGNMENTS"   >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "===================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "select char(grantee,15) as grantee, char(granteetype,1) as type, char(dbadmauth,1) as dbadmin,
char(securityadmauth,1) as secadmin, char(sqladmauth,1) as sqladmin, char(dataaccessauth,1) as
 access, char(accessctrlauth,1) as accessctrl, char(wlmadmauth,1) as wlmadmin, char(loadauth,1) as load, 
char(createtabauth,1) as createtable, char(bindaddauth,1) as bindadd, char(connectauth,1) as connect, 
char(implschemaauth,1) as implschema, char(libraryadmauth,1) as libadmin from syscat.dbauth" order by grantee  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "=============================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo " 11. PASSTHROUGH ACCESS FROM OTHER DATABASES"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "=============================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "select char(grantor,8) as grantor, char(grantortype,1) as type,
char (grantee,15) as grantee, char (granteetype,1) as grantee_type, char(servername,8) as servername
from SYSCAT.PASSTHRUAUTH"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "============================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo " 12. ROLES AND MEMBERS IN THE DATABASE"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "============================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "select char(grantor,8) as grantor, char(grantortype,1) as type,
char(grantee,8) as grantee, char(granteetype,1) as grantee_type, char(rolename,15) as role_name, char(admin,1) as admin from SYSCAT.ROLEAUTH" order by grantee  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "==============================================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "13. DISTINCT OWNERS OF TABLES (Should Not Be Public or Users)"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "==============================================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "select distinct owner from SYSCAT.TABLES"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "=================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "14. ACCESS LEVEL TO SYSTEM TABLES"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "=================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "select char(grantor,8) as grantor, char(grantee,8) as grantee, char(ttname,33) as tablename, char(controlauth,1) as control, char(alterauth,1) as alter, char(deleteauth,1) as delete, char(insertauth,1) as insert, char(selectauth,1) as select, char(granteetype,1) as grantee_type from sysibm.systabauth 
where grantee not in ('DB2INST1')"  order by grantee  >> $working_dir/$logfile ; 

echo "====================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "15. LIST ALL SCHEMAS"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "====================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "select char(schemaname,15) as name, char(owner,10) as owner, char(auditpolicyname,12) as auditpolicy from syscat.schemata" >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "======================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "16. ACCESS TO SCHEMAS"    >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "======================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "SELECT char(GRANTOR,8) as grantor, char(grantee,12) as grantee, char(granteetype,1) as type, 
char(schemaname, 10) as schema_name, char(alterinauth,1) as alter, char(createinauth,1) as create, 
char(dropinauth,1) as drop from syscat.schemaauth" order by grantee >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "==================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "17. DATABASE CONFIGURATION"           >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "===================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 get db cfg  >>$working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "==================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "18. DATABASE MANAGER CONFIGURATION"   >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "===================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 get database manager configuration  >>$working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "=========================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "19. PUBLIC ACCESS TO SYSTEM CATALOG VIEWS"   >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "=========================================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "select char(grantee,8) as grantee, char(ttname,30) as table from sysibm.systabauth where tcreator='SYSCAT' and grantee='PUBLIC'"  >>$working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "================================"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "20. ACCESS TO SYSTEM TABLESPACE"   >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "================================"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "select char(grantee,8) as grantee, char(tbspace,10) as tablespace from sysibm.systbspaceauth where grantee='PUBLIC'"  >>$working_dir/$logfile ;

echo "=============================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "21. USE OF SYSTEM TABLESPACE"    >> $working_dir/$logfile ;
echo "=============================="  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 "select char(tabschema,8)as tableschema, char(tabname,8) as tablename, char(tbspace,10) as tablespace from syscat.tables where tabschema not in ('ADMINISTRATOR','SYSIBM','SYSTOOLS') and tbspace in ('SYSCATSPACE','SYSTOOLSPACE','SYSTOOLSTMPSPACE','TEMPSPACE')"  >>$working_dir/$logfile ;



echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++SCRIPT COMPLETED+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++"  >> $working_dir/$logfile ;

db2 terminate 


fi


echo "";

done

echo "Audit Ended `date`" >> $working_dir/$logfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to record the database name in the reports ($logfile) then you have the database-name already in your script (in loop control variable $i ).

If you want a single $logfile (to include all databases, which seems a questionable decision) then echo headers and footers to the $logfile after successful db-connection, and after disconnect/connect-reset from that database. Everything between the db header and footer would then pertain to that database.

Another option is to have one $logfile per database, for example $dbname.$logfile, which may be simpler, especially of database ownerships are for different groups/responsiblities in the organization.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways I have done is as follows.

```
os_info=$h_name,$os_name,$os_mversion


# paragraph grep'ing is not possible in Linux, use Perl version
db2 list db directory | perl -00ne 'if ($_ =~ /Indirect/) {chomp($_); printf "%s\n",$_}' | grep -i alias|awk {'print $4'} | while read DB_NAME
do

    db2 connect to $DB_NAME >>/dev/null
    is_connected=$(db2 connect to $DB_NAME | awk {'print $1'} | head -1)
    #echo $is_connected
    if [ "$is_connected" = "SQL1776N" ]; then
            echo '-1, *HADR Secondary*' > xcvsfdgerwersdfs.dat
    else
            db2 "CALL GET_DBSIZE_INFO(?, ?, ?, -1)" | grep "Parameter Value" | head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{print $4}' > xcvsfdgerwersdfs.dat
    fi

    db_size=$(cat xcvsfdgerwersdfs.dat)
    echo $os_info,$db2_version,$DB2INSTANCE,$DB_NAME,$db_size

done
```

I have databases on Linux and AIX so I am using Perl snippets for certain things. I leverage DB2 catalog to find/identify the available DBs and collection their information.